# Android NDK error when using FFmpeg in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

Hi I am using FFmpeg library.I have used code from [appunite](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg).I have imported both FFmpegLibrary & FFmpegExample in Eclipse.

But when I try to generate .so file using Android NDK & Cygwin I am getting following error message.

```
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/yuv2rgb/Android.mk:ffmpeg-prebuilt: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that jni/ffmpeg-build/armeabi/libffmpeg.so exists  or that its path is correct
/cygdrive/D/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8c/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:43: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

If anyone has successfully used this library.Please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: did you find the answer for this?

Comment: @TharakaNirmana Yes I found it.

Comment: I am searching a way to create a video by combining an audio file and an image, within the android code. I figured out the command for that: ffmpeg -i allmapeople.mp3 -i Penguins.jpg video_finale.mpg I tried many 2 tutorials using ffmpeg that generates the .so file. But I still could not find out a way to combine an audio and an image. Please help me to do this in android code!!!

Comment: @TharakaNirmana Not sure but please check https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically problem was with ffmpeg lib.I was not able to compile ffmpeg lib on Windows 7. I switched to Ubuntu & tried [AppUnite](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg) & after spending so many hours it was working.

Comment: Can you please also suggest me answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892218/ffmpeg-ndk-symbol-android-log-warn-could-not-be-resolved