# linphone on windows building error

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, ffmpeg, linphone

i have downloaded the linphone for Android from Github. 
i have also followed all the instructions in readme file. the problem is that when i run `ndk-build` command it produce below error .

```
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/..//submodules/externals/build/ffmpeg/Android.mk:avutil-linphone: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that jni/..//submodules/externals/build/ffmpeg/arm/libavutil/libavutil-linphone-arm.so exists  or that its path is correct
/cygdrive/c/development/android-ndk-r9b/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:45: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

`what this error mean ? & how can i resolve this?` i already spent many hours to searchout this error but no success...
my OS is window 7 & i used cygwin for commands.

i have found same question on SO
[Android NDK error when using FFmpeg in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13974839/676755)

it says `Basically problem was with ffmpeg lib.I was not able to compile ffmpeg lib on Windows 7. I switched to Ubuntu & tried AppUnite & after spending so many hours it was working.`

```
is it not possible to build linphone on windows ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Altought I am not familiar with the linphone library, from a generic view, you can put the libavutil-linphone-arm.so under 'workspace/yourandroidprojectroot/lib' directory,

and then modify your Android.mk which is under 'workspace/yourandroidprojectroot/jni' like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := avutil-linphone-arm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../lib/libavutil-linphone-arm.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := yourownmodule
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := yourownmodule.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=  avutil-linphone-arm

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

For ABI selection of shared libraries, you can refer to the PREBUILTS.html under android-ndk/docs